# Safe range for EventId.Id in ASP.NET Core logging mechanism

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to [log some events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore2x) in my ASP.NET Core application and I don't want to collide with another library. **Is there a safe range for custom EventIds [EventId.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-event-id)?**

All ASP.NET Core logs that I found, has `EventId.Id` lower then `1000`. But EF has arround `100,000`.

I need this, so I can easy filter my events from other events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventId` is application specific. There's no "safe range". It's just whatever you want your event ids to be.

Comment: I understand but some are used by Framework and libraries. For example: I thought that .Net Core would take 1 - 1000, official external libraries (like EF) 1000 - 10000 and custom (app defined) from 10000.

Comment: The point is that the event is is *contextual*. It only has meaning in relation to a particular application. It's used as a simple way to route you to documentation. It's not something you should be filtering on alone: only in relationship to a particular application.

Comment: Yes but every asp.net application will use certain EventIds because the framework logs certain events under certain EventIds out of the box. You shouldn't use HTTP status codes, for example, because the framework will log them and use the status code as the eventId by default. While I agree that filtering on it alone isn't that valuable, but using EventIds that will collide with framework EventIds will make your own EventIds useless for filtering.